# Get jenkins all master/child job details using groovy

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

I need to get jenkins all master/child job details like start time, end time, review id which got integrated in current jenkin job for all the master and children jobs and put the same in a json array. I have written below script to get the details but not able to get start and end time of the job for master/child and how do we differentiate between master job detail and child job detail data.

```
    import hudson.model.*

map1=[:]
map1["BUILD_NUMBER"]=(build.getEnvVars()['BUILD_NUMBER'])
map1["PARENT_BUILD_NUMBER"]=(build.getEnvVars()['BUILD_NUMBER'])
map1["JOB_NAME"]=(build.getEnvVars()['JOB_NAME'])
map1["PHASE_NAME"]=(build.getEnvVars()['JOB_NAME'])
map1["Status"]=(build.getEnvVars()['PHASE_RESULT'])
map1["Branch"]="master"
map1["JOB_URL"]=(build.getEnvVars()['JOB_URL'])
map1["START_TIME"]=(build.getEnvVars()['timestamp'])
map1["END_TIME"]=(build.getEnvVars()['buildEndTime'])

def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
json MasterJob: map1
println "json output: "
println groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString())
```

[*Jenkin job image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0fMA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information using Jenkins' REST API. It provides build information in various formats (including JSON). Example url:

http://JENKINS_HOST:8080/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?pretty=true

You have also a link to REST API documentation in bottom right corner of your Jenkins instance.